# Flood Fill Recursion Algorithm with Vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am implementing flood fill with depth-first search algorithm in C++ in which it works perfectly with arrays but somehow broke with vector. Here's my code

Array based:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define W 10
#define H 10

void display(char layout[][W]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
            std::cout << layout[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void dfs(char layout[][W], int x, int y, char old, char _new) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= W || y < 0 || y >= H) return;
    if (layout[y][x] != old) return;
    if (layout[y][x] == _new) return;

    layout[y][x] = _new;
    
    //debug
    system("cls");
    display(layout);
    system("pause");
    
    dfs(layout, x + 1, y, old, _new);
    dfs(layout, x - 1, y, old, _new);
    dfs(layout, x, y + 1, old, _new);
    dfs(layout, x, y - 1, old, _new);
}

void floodFill(char layout[][W], int x, int y, char _new) {
    char old = layout[y][x];
    if (old == _new) return;
    
    dfs(layout, x, y, old, _new);
}

int main() {
    char layout[H][W] = { 
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
    };
    floodFill(layout, 0,4,'0');
    system("cls");
    display(layout);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Vector-based:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void display(vector< vector<char> >layout) {
    int H = layout.size();
    int W = layout[0].size();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
            cout << layout[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void dfs(vector< vector<char> >layout, int x, int y, char old, char _new) {
    int H = layout.size();
    int W = layout[0].size();
    
    if (x < 0 || x >= W || y < 0 || y >= H) return;
    if (layout[y][x] != old) return;
    if (layout[y][x] == _new) return;

    layout[y][x] = _new;
    
    //debug
    system("cls");
    display(layout);
    system("pause");
    
    dfs(layout, x + 1, y, old, _new);
    dfs(layout, x - 1, y, old, _new);
    dfs(layout, x, y + 1, old, _new);
    dfs(layout, x, y - 1, old, _new);
}

void floodFill(vector< vector<char> > layout, int x, int y, char _new) {
    char old = layout[y][x];
    if (old == _new) return;

    dfs(layout, x, y, old, _new);
}

int main() {
    vector< vector<char> > layout { 
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#'},
    };
    floodFill(layout, 0, 4, '0');
    display(layout);
    return 0;
}
```

Array-based code works perfectly as expected, but vector-based code works until it can't find anymore neighbors and somehow revert back some elements to its old state, creating more neighbors and making it recur endlessly. Here's what happened:

The vector-based code worked to this part which is where the program should stop.

```
# # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #

0 0 0 0   # # # # #
0 0 0 0   # # # # #
0 0 0 0   # # # # #
0 0 0 0   # # # # #
0 0 0 0   # # # # #
0 0 0 0   # # # # #
```

Yet, the next recursion somehow revert back some elements to its old state and creating more neighbors.

```
# # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #

0 0 0 0   # # # # #
0 0 0 0   # # # # #
0 0 0 0   # # # # #
0 0 0 0   # # # # #
0 0 0 #   # # # # #
# # 0 #   # # # # #
```

This keeps happening endlessly, creating an infinite loop. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Edit:
After I looked at it again, I kind of see where the problem is. After the program reached layout[0][9] (left bottom), instead of returning to start it stops returning at layout[2][8] and continuing the recursion to the third dfs function which is going down, therefore sort of revert back the recursion after it. This will happen to all elements with at least two possible neighbors. But if that's the case, it should've happened with the array-based code as well. Why it doesn't happen with the array-based code but happens with vector-based?

Comment: You are passing arrays by reference (which is the only way they can be passed), but vectors by value. Each recursive call operates on its copy of the vector; any changes it makes aren't visible to the caller.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I see the problem. I didn't know that array and vector had such different method.

Comment: This is the heritage of C: C arrays cannot be assigned and decay to a pointer in function parameters always but `struct`s can be assigned and can be passed by value. A `class` is similar to a `struct` (except that contents is `private` by default). `std::vector` is a class template. Hence, the difference how arrays and vectors are handled.